# AngularJS - GET response unable to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, http

I have a simple view where a bunch of JSON data gets displayed. The problem I'm facing is when I try to display the directly from within the factory the data is displayed but the same data when access via a `$http.get` request is not getting displayed! The data is being fetched but the JSON format is changing during the fetch request.

My controller code is as below:

```
angular.module('ngCribs')
.controller('cribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory) {
  $scope.cribs;

  cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.cribs = data;
  }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

My Factory code:

```
angular.module('ngCribs')
.factory('cribsFactory', function($http) {

  function getCribs() {
    return $http.get('data.json');
  }

  return {
    getCribs: getCribs
  };

});
```

The JSON object as I have created:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Condo",
    "price": 220000,
    "address": "213 Grove Street",
    "description": "Excellent place, really nice"
  },
  {
    "type": "House",
    "price": 410000,
    "address": "7823 Winding Way",
    "description": "Excellent place, really nice and beautiful"
  },
  {
    "type": "Duplex",
    "price": 395000,
    "address": "2834 River Lane",
    "description": "Great, really nice"
  }
]
```

What is getting outputted on the console:

[image: Here is a snapshot of the consoled object]

Here is a plunker link to my progress so far

https://plnkr.co/edit/GTZJC2cCCzE1KfLAD5wF?p=preview

As you can see in the plunker the data isn't getting displayed. Please help and guide me as to where I'm making a mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: use `data.data` to get the api response. `data.data` is your array object. Replace this line as `$scope.cribs = data.data;'

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbvW23Sb7qavtQI2ALsa?p=preview

Comment: As suggested by @Nhan, just update your code to get the data, then I think it should work
$scope.cribs = data.data;

Answer (score 1):

In `cribsController.js`, you are getting the whole response object, change it to `data.data` to access the response data only.

```
cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $scope.cribs = data.data;
}, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div class="well" ng-repeat="crib in cribs">`

To

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="crib in cribs.data">
```

You should use data.data in order for you to loop.